# Using single-command docker image in another docker image (php, nodejs, phantomjs)

Tags: docker, devops, administration

I have two docker images: php and phantomjs.
Im using them to build simple command-line script application.
Also im having convinient run.bat script that contains:

`docker run -it --rm --name my-running-script -v %cd%:/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp php:7.0-cli php`

What should i do to add nodejs into my php image? 
I want to be able to use something like "phantomjs --help" inside php container.

I've tried to search documentation for similar issues, but havent found any tips on that.

This is phantomjs image that im using: https://hub.docker.com/r/wernight/phantomjs/
for php image im using:
https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

Answer (score 1):

If you want phantomjs inside your php container, instead of using two docker images one with `php` and other with `phantomjs` you just need to build your own cutom docker image with both these packages.

It seems you are using `debian:stretch` as base image for `phantomjs` https://hub.docker.com/r/wernight/phantomjs/~/dockerfile/

You just need to google for installing php on debian. Probably it should be one more line in your dockerfile `apt-get install -y php`. Then build this image and use it.